# Set maximun of checked values in checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working in a fun project in HTML and JavaScript. 
I have created a form including a checkbox section where I want to set max choices to one.

Current HTML:

```
<legend>Choose</legend> 
<ul class="checkbox"> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1" /><label for="cb1">1</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2" /><label for="cb2">2</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="3" /><label for="cb3">3</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="4" /><label for="cb4">4</label></li> 

</ul>
```

If you check more than one box you'll get an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop('checked')` to find if the other check box is selected,hope this helps

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  if($(this).prop('checked'))
  {
  var status = 0;
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(e){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
          $(this).prop('checked',false)
          status = 1;
       }
  
     })
  
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend>Choose</legend> 
<ul class="checkbox"> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1" /><label for="cb1">1</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2" /><label for="cb2">2</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="3" /><label for="cb3">3</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="4" /><label for="cb4">4</label></li> 

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Radio buttons. But still, you want to use checkbox then check following example**

```js
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
  if(n>1){
  alert('more then one')
  }
};
countChecked();
 
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend>Choose</legend> 
<ul class="checkbox"> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1" class='cb' /><label for="cb1">1</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2" class='cb' /><label for="cb2">2</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="3" class='cb' /><label for="cb3">3</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="4" class='cb' /><label for="cb4">4</label></li> 

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use an `<input type="radio">` if you want only one selected. You can also use the following implementation if you need to add a limit > 1. Just change the `MAX_CHECKED` value:

```js
var MAX_CHECKED = 2;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
    if (checked.length > MAX_CHECKED) {
      event.target.checked = false;
      alert('Too many checked already!');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<legend>Choose</legend>
<ul class="checkbox">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1" /><label for="cb1">1</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2" /><label for="cb2">2</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="3" /><label for="cb3">3</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="4" /><label for="cb4">4</label></li>
</ul>
```